# Removing 50Hz flicker on lights

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

I've just moved into a new flat, and in the corridor and bathroom, we have these lights as shown in the picture, and they shine with a slight flicker (which I assume is a mains 50Hz). It's very fast, and you can only really tell if you look at the light, but it is still quite annoying. Is there anything that can be done about it, apart from taking them out? (I'm in a rented place so that's not really an option.)

[image: light]

Comment: Is this a fluorescent fixture? Some people are more sensitive than others to flicker which is apparently at twice the line frequency so the light flickers at 100 hz. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold

Comment: If it is a fluorescent fixture, is it using an old-style magnetic ballast or an electronic ballast?

Comment: Are magnetic ballasts being used anymore? Do modern electronic balasts flicker light output? This looks like a new, modern fixture. Are there meters that can detect flicker in the light output?

Comment: It must be a magnetic ballast if it flickers.   @JimStewart magnetic ballasts are everywhere including in some newer CFLs (of the type that have a proprietary socket).  I'm aware of a 12 year old building that has literally thousands of them.

Comment: If it is a rental, have you talked to the landlord about the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No doubt of it, that's a fluorescent.  Lights like this give fluorescents a bad name.   Fluorescents are really quite good these days.

Pop the cover off, get the model number and figure out what type of bulb it takes.  See if you can lay eyes on the ballast itself, to get a sense of its shape and size.

From there, go shopping for an electronic ballast for that bulb type.  Look for one that will physically fit in that fixture.  The shape and mounting are highly standardized.  An electronic ballast will not flicker or buzz, will start instantly (or quickly if it's a rapid-start or programmed start) in all conditions including deep cold.

Comment: so if it flashes on and off a couple of times before turning on properly, it must have a magnetic ballast right?

Comment: Yes, that even suggests a type with a starter.  The starter is trying to create a voltage spike (needed to strike the lamp) by interrupting a big inductor at the right moment in the AC power cycle sinewave.  It's a dumb relay and has no idea *when* that is, so it just tries over and over til it gets lucky.  By contrast, a programmed-start ballast will energize the preheat filaments until their impedance indicates they are warmed up... then fires the voltage spike to strike the arc, repeating until struck, then chops AC at around 10KHz to avoid flicker.